# Get text from child div

Tags: jquery

I have a `<div>` where I have three tabs in it. Within the `<div>` all three tabs have their own `<div>`. I want to log the name of the tab every time a user clicks on it. This is the code:

```js
jQuery('.hptabs').mousedown(function(e) {
  var tabname = jQuery(this).attr.('text');
  console.log(tabname);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hptabs">
  <div class="tab active">Tab 1</div>
  <div class="tab second">Tab 2</div>
  <div class="tab">Tab 3</div>
</div>
```

So the result is that get all three names in the log instead of just logging the one on which I clicked.

Comment: You have a typo in `.attr.('text')` (should be `.attr('text')`), but there is no text attribute anyway. You probably want `.text()` or `.html()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code,

```
jQuery('.hptabs div').click(function(e)  {
    var tabname = jQuery(this).text();
    console.log(tabname);
});
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Elroy Thanks,Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.tab').click(function(e)  {
    var tabname = jQuery(this).text();
    console.log(tabname);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event delegation using the second parameter in the `on` call. (`click` or `mousedown` direct event handlers are deprecated from v1.7 onwards. Ref: http://api.jquery.com/on/) Also, if you are extracting text just use the `.text()` method right away. `text` is not an attribute so `attr` cannot be used here.

```js
$('.hptabs').on("click", ".tab", function(e)  {
  var tabname = $(this).text();
  console.log(tabname);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hptabs">
    <div class="tab active">Tab 1</div>
    <div class="tab second">Tab 2</div>
    <div class="tab">Tab 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is proper code as per your description.

```
jQuery('.hptabs div').click(function(){
    var tabName=jQuery(this).text();
    console.log(tabName);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're catching `click` on the entire div, and so `this` is that `div`. Naturally, all three tabs' text is included.

Catch clicks on the tabs themselves instead:

```js
jQuery('.hptabs .tab').mousedown(function(e)  {
    var tabname = jQuery(this).text();
    console.log(tabname);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hptabs">
    <div class="tab active">Tab 1</div>
    <div class="tab second">Tab 2</div>
    <div class="tab">Tab 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below codes:

```
    var container = $('.hptabs');
    container.on('click', '.tab', function(e)  {
      var tabText = $(this).text();
      console.log(tabText);
    });
```